# clEnqueueNDRangeKernel triggers CL_INVALID_MEM_OBJECT (-38)

Tags: c++, opencl, nvidia

I am using the C++ binding for OpenCL and when enqueuing one of my kernels I get a `cl::Error` which says `-38 (CL_INVALID_MEM_OBJECT)` for `clEnqueueNDRangeKernel`.

This error is not listed as one of the possible errors of [clEnqueueNDRangeKernel](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clEnqueueNDRangeKernel.html).
The notify function gives me following output:

> CL_INVALID_MEM_OBJECT error executing CL_COMMAND_NDRANGE_KERNEL on GeForce GTX 560 (Device 0).

I have yet to find a minimal example that exhibits this behaviour.

**What can cause this kind of error when calling this function?**

Using google I only found this [answer](http://www.khronos.org/message_boards/showthread.php/8402-clEnqueueNDRangeKernel-Error-38?p=29198&viewfull=1#post29198) yet. It states that I need to re`setKernelArg` an attached memory object if it has been updated. (At least that is my interpretation of it and there is no detailed explanation of what updated means.) 
However, I doubt that this is correct, although I cannot prove it. Maybe you know an official source on this?

### Update

After some testing I found that adding a `__global const float*` parameter to the kernel introduced the error. I also found that the error does only occur every time if I `clSetKernelArg` this new argument after another (already existing) argument. If I do so before the other argument is set, it works every second time. Of course this is not an option as I need to be able to set the argument at any time.

### Update 2

I noticed that stepping through the code with a debugging "reintroduces" the error in the version where I set the new argument before the other one. (This means the error occurs again every time.)

Could this be some kind of race condition? I do not use multithreading myself, but in the debugger there are 7 threads which could come from Qt or OpenCL.

### Minimal Working Example

```
#include <CL/cl.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

#define STRINGIFY(x) #x

std::string kernel = STRINGIFY(
__kernel void apply(__global const float *param1)
{
}
);


template <class T>
cl::Buffer genBuffer(const cl::Context &context, const std::vector<T> &data,
                        cl_mem_flags flags = CL_MEM_READ_ONLY)
{
        return cl::Buffer(context, flags | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR,
                                data.size() * sizeof(data[0]),
                                const_cast<T*>(&data[0]));
}

int main()
{
        std::vector<cl::Platform> clPlatforms;
        cl::Platform::get(&clPlatforms);
        cl_context_properties props[] = {
                CL_CONTEXT_PLATFORM, (cl_context_properties)clPlatforms[0](),
                0};
        cl::Context clContext = cl::Context(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, props);
        std::vector<cl::Device> devices = clContext.getInfo<CL_CONTEXT_DEVICES>();
        if(devices.empty())
        {
                std::cerr << "No devices found!\n";
                exit(-1);
        }
        cl::Device clDevice = devices[0];
        cl::CommandQueue clQueue = cl::CommandQueue(clContext, clDevice, 0, 0);
        cl::Program program(clContext, cl::Program::Sources(1,
                                std::make_pair(kernel.c_str(), kernel.size())));
        program.build(devices);
        cl::Kernel kernel(program, "apply");

        //this introduces the error
        kernel.setArg(0, genBuffer(clContext, std::vector<cl_float>(100));
        //the error is triggered here
        clQueue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(kernel, cl::NullRange, cl::NDRange(100), cl::NullRange);
}
```

Comment: Some code would be useful. nVIDIA is famous for giving errors out of the spec.

Comment: @DarkZeros: I am working on it. I hope for some hints which parts might be causing the problem because there are many dependencies in the code which makes finding an MWE harder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem was that I attached a buffer to a kernel assuming the kernel would retain the buffer. Then I destructed all referencing `cl::Buffer`/`Memory` objects which caused the OpenCL implementation to delete the buffer.

---

After running my program through valgrind I noticed that the `opencl.so` accessed memory of an object that was freed earlier in a `cl::~Buffer` subroutine. Reading up on [`clSetKernelArg`](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.1/docs/man/xhtml/clSetKernelArg.html) I noticed:

> Users may not rely on a kernel object to retain objects specified as argument values to the kernel.

The undeterministic behaviour clearly is a result of the driver accessing a freed memory area thereby entering UB land.

### Corrected MWE

```
#include <CL/cl.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

#define STRINGIFY(x) #x

std::string kernel = STRINGIFY(
__kernel void apply(__global const float *param1)
{
}
);


template <class T>
cl::Buffer genBuffer(const cl::Context &context, const std::vector<T> &data,
                        cl_mem_flags flags = CL_MEM_READ_ONLY)
{
        return cl::Buffer(context, flags | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR,
                                data.size() * sizeof(data[0]),
                                const_cast<T*>(&data[0]));
}

int main()
{
        std::vector<cl::Platform> clPlatforms;
        cl::Platform::get(&clPlatforms);
        cl_context_properties props[] = {
                CL_CONTEXT_PLATFORM, (cl_context_properties)clPlatforms[0](),
                0};
        cl::Context clContext = cl::Context(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, props);
        std::vector<cl::Device> devices = clContext.getInfo<CL_CONTEXT_DEVICES>();
        if(devices.empty())
        {
                std::cerr << "No devices found!\n";
                exit(-1);
        }
        cl::Device clDevice = devices[0];
        cl::CommandQueue clQueue = cl::CommandQueue(clContext, clDevice, 0, 0);
        cl::Program program(clContext, cl::Program::Sources(1,
                                std::make_pair(kernel.c_str(), kernel.size())));
        program.build(devices);
        cl::Kernel kernel(program, "apply");

        //this version triggers the error
        //kernel.setArg(0, genBuffer(clContext, std::vector<cl_float>(100));

        //This is how it is done correctly
        cl::Buffer buffer = genBuffer(clContext, std::vector<cl_float>(100));
        kernel.setArg(0, buffer);

        clQueue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(kernel, cl::NullRange, cl::NDRange(100), cl::NullRange);
}
```